# Show that $f$ is also continuous and linear.

Tags: functional-analysis

> $X$ is a Frechet space, $\{f_n\}\subset X^*$ is a sequence of continuous linear functionals and the sum $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges for every $x\in X$.

Showing linearity is easy. But for continuity, since this is pointwise convergence it is hard to prove it. Fix $x_0\in X$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is $\delta_n>0$ such that if $d(x,x_0)<\delta_n$ then $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$. But now how do we get a common $\delta$ to show the continuity of $f$?

Comment: Looks like Banach-Steinhaus.

Comment: Banach-Steinhaus is for Banach space, here you would rather apply Osgood Theorem: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Osgood_(Funktionalanalysis)

Comment: Banach-Steinhaus holds for domains which are Frechet spaces or, more generally, *barrelled locally convex spaces*.

Comment: @daw, could you please comment the English version of that link. I don't see a way to translate it.